# Why when I changed the test batch size in tensorflow, result was different

Tags: tensorflow

Here is my train code:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2, 3])
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(10)

_, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        cell = cell,
        inputs = x,
        dtype = tf.float32)
# train
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    x_ = np.ones([2,2,3],np.float32)
    output = sess.run(state, feed_dict= {x: x_})
    print output    
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess,'./model')
```

The result is:

```
[[ 0.12851571 -0.23994535  0.23123585 -0.00047993 -0.02450397
  -0.21048039 -0.18786618  0.04458345 -0.08603278 -0.08259721]
 [ 0.12851571 -0.23994535  0.23123585 -0.00047993 -0.02450397
  -0.21048039 -0.18786618  0.04458345 -0.08603278 -0.08259721]]
```

Here is my test code:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2, 3])
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(10)

_, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        cell = cell,
        inputs = x,
        dtype = tf.float32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    x_ = np.ones([1,2,3],np.float32)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.restore(sess,'./model')
    output = sess.run(state, feed_dict= {x: x_})
    print output
```

Then I get:

```
[[ 0.12851571 -0.23994535  0.2312358  -0.00047993 -0.02450397 
  -0.21048039 -0.18786621  0.04458345 -0.08603278 -0.08259721]]
```

You see, result has changed slightly. When I set the test batch to 2, the result is same as  train result. So what's wrong? My tf version is 0.12

Answer (score 0):

## An update (not an answer)

The `tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell` and `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` are both deprecated and replaced with `tf.keras.layers.GRU`.

Using the deprecated functions, it appears you don't even need to save and restore the model or even run it multiple times.  All you need is to run it on an odd batch size and use tf.float32 as the dtype and the last result will be slightly off.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2, 3])
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(10)

_, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        cell = cell,
        inputs = x,
        dtype = tf.float32)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

x_ = np.ones([3,2,3],np.float32)
output = sess.run(state, feed_dict= {x: x_})
print(output)
```

Returns results like this

```
[[ 0.03649516 -0.08052824 -0.0539998   0.2995336  -0.12542574 -0.04339318
   0.3872745   0.08844283 -0.14555818 -0.4216033 ]
 [ 0.03649516 -0.08052824 -0.0539998   0.2995336  -0.12542574 -0.04339318
   0.3872745   0.08844283 -0.14555818 -0.4216033 ]
 [ 0.03649516 -0.08052824 -0.05399981  0.2995336  -0.12542574 -0.04339318
   0.38727456  0.08844285 -0.14555818 -0.4216033 ]]
```

The anomaly only seems to appear in the last row for odd length batches.

An alternative view is, that a single batch is correct, and all even sized batches are off and everything other than the last row of odd sized batches is off.

It does not seem to happen for dtype=float64 or dtype=float16, both of which seem stable.

Furthermore, this issue is only in the hidden state and does not seem to appear in the regular output.